# Oracle linked server warning message 'has an unresolved reference to object' in database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I have created a database project (VS2012) from an existing sql server database (Sql 2012) which in turn uses Oracle linked server. Some of the Store Procedures in that database uses this linked server '[SMAC]..[SMACADMINISTRATOR].[BOND]'. When I build the database project, it gives lot of warnings as 'The procedure xxxxx has an unresolved reference to object.

How can I suppress these warning messages?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Project Properties dialog and type in the SQL warnings to suppress (it's in the Build section, named "Suppress Transact-SQL warnings").

There is also a References Section in the Solution Explorer in the Project, perhaps you can add a reference there? Although perhaps not practial if there are many Procedures being referenced.. then it could be better to suppress all warnings of the given type.

Comment: Thanks..I have suppressed the warning as you told, It worked for me. One more thing, Can we create .dacpac for Oracle database using Visual Studio

Comment: I would say not no, not out of the box, afaik. Here is some info on Oracle and Visual Studio: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html